# Support for WACOM Intuos Draw in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wacom

I´m looking to purchase a WACOM Intuos Draw for my laptop which runs on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But the only problem is is that I don`t know if there is any good support on Ubuntu for this product.

The reason I want to use the WACOM Intuos is to make notes for my mathematical courses and I hate to have 4 noteblocks (1 for each course) while I can store it on my laptop.

Could anyone of you share your experiences of this product on Ubuntu?

PS: I already found a youtube video showing a working WACOM Intuos Draw! But still I`m very curious about your experiences!

Comment: My sister uses one, and it works fine. I'm sure you can get the pressure levels working in GIMP somehow, but I tested it on Ubuntu (she uses it under Windows) and it's plug-n-play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using my Wacom Intuos Draw for last couple of months with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Dell XPS 13. Except for scroll, rest works fine for me. I'm still looking for ways to make the scroll work.

Please note though my use case is mostly programming, so I have not used this with GIMP or any such applications at all

Answer (score 0):

I have been using it to teach mathematics from a laptop connected to a projector and it works great. The buttons don't map properly, but that is what keyboards are for. The pen works great and it can switch between monitors easily.